# How should I go about handling exceptions thrown within a WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf, service

I've created a service that listens out for commands to launch executables, which is hosted via a WPF application with a list-box that displays messages to the user.

The thing is, the service could potentially throw exceptions, which I want to catch and display in the list-box; the only problem with this is that I'm not sure how to go about catching these exceptions, as the service is, of course, run from a `ServiceHost`.

The best thing I can really think of doing, without tying the service to the UI (I want to avoid this so that I can re-use it in, say a console application), is to add an event to the service that's invoked when an exception is thrown, where I'll pass the exception into the handler.

My service is created outside of the `ServiceHost` anyway (as a singleton object), as it has an event for when an executable is launched.

Is this the best way to go about this, and if not, what is?

Comment: Read about FaultContract in WCF service.....https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752208(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks @Viru, but I'm not sure that's what I'm after; I'm not looking to notify the client of the error, but rather the server. Unless I'm reading things wrong and it's used for both?

Comment: are you doing self hosting? also it would great if you can put some code which you have tried until now...it will really help me to understand the problem

Comment: @Viru if you actually read the question the OP states they are hosting in a WPF container. Also FaultContract is not what the OP is looking for here. Did you only read the title of the post or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The thing is, the service could potentially throw exceptions, which I
>   want to catch and display in the list-box

I think the safest thing to do here would be for your service operation to log exceptions, either to a file or database.

Your WPF app would then need some mechanism to consume this log.

This keeps your service and the hosting container completely decoupled.

However, if you do want to couple your WPF app and ServiceHost together, look at the [WPF/WCF hosting sample on codeplex](http://wpfservicehost.codeplex.com/). There is communication going on between the ServiceHost and the host application there.

> is there any particular reason to consider an event as an unsafe
>   method of passing thrown exceptions to the hosting container?

Not unsafe as such. I guess it's about complexity. In effect you have two components masquerading as a single component. Even though one component is acting as a hosting container for the other, they should still be considered separate.

If an exception is thrown from inside a service operation, the handling of the exception should be internal to the service. This is one of the principals of SOA, that services should be [autonomous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_autonomy_principle).

If there are side effects to the exception that other components are interested in, then these can be communicated to the outside world in the form of an event.

I guess the point here is should the event simply contain the exception? The exception is meaningful inside the service boundary, but what in fact does the exception mean? There may in-fact be many different reasons you will get an exception, in which case you should create different event types for each failure reason, some of which may not be appropriate to expose outside of the service.

However, I am probably overthinking this. WPF is a valid, [Microsoft-supported](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730158(v=vs.110).aspx) hosting container for WCF, and the scenario you are implementing is probably quite common.

Sorry for the rambling - I'm trying to arrive at something making me generally uneasy about your solution, but I'm not doing a great job of getting there...

Comment: Thanks @Tom, is there any particular reason to consider an event as an unsafe method of passing thrown exceptions to the hosting container? I've since tried using an event, and it works like a charm, but I just wondered if it's a good (and safe) way of going about the problem?

Comment: @Lee.J.Baxter please see update to my asnwer - apologies for the rambling

Comment: no problem, thanks for your input! I guess the real question is, "is there a correct way to do it?"; it's probably not the norm, but it seems to be a nice, efficient way of telling outside components that an exception has been thrown by the service. I haven't come across anything like this before, but then again I've never really dealt with services up until this point!